# C# Interop Word

Tags: c#, office-interop

What is the C# Interop Word equivalent to word macro:
 `varObj.Type = wdInlineShapeEmbeddedOLEObject` ?
Below is an extraction from my C# program.  Everything else works but the line that is commented out.  I am new to C# and appreciate the help.  Thanks.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

namespace FindEmbeddedObjects
{
   class Program
   {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {

          foreach (var tempLoopVar_varObj in winword.ActiveDocument.InlineShapes)
          {
            //if (varObj.Type = wdInlineShapeEmbeddedOLEObject) // what is the C# equivalent
              fileCount++;
            //}
          }

       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would the following help?

```
using Word=Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
....
Word.Application wordApp = new Word.Application();
Word.Document document = wordApp.Documents.Open("C:\\myDoc.docx");
int fileCount = 0;

foreach (Word.InlineShape tempLoopVar_varObj in wordApp.ActiveDocument.InlineShapes)
{
    if (tempLoopVar_varObj.Type == Word.WdInlineShapeType.wdInlineShapeEmbeddedOLEObject)
    {
        fileCount++;
    }
}
```

Comment: To access the `ActiveDocument`, you need an `Application` object of type `Word.Application`. This `Application` opens or creates a `Document` which is then the `ActiveDocument`.

Comment: Thanks.  I am new to C#, so I will do a google search to find out how to do that.

Comment: Please have a look at the extended answer.

Comment: Thanks.  But, intellisense does not find type inlineshape.  So, InlineShape tempLoopVar_varObj is not valid for me.  I must be missing something.

Comment: There was a missing `Word.` reference to the namespace `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word`